# Why does await _navigationService.NavigateAsync not work in OnNavigatedTo function

Tags: xamarin, prism

Been at this for days. Very simple logic.
Jump to Home page if bla = true skipping the login page.

I've stripped down the code to demo this.
Login button navigates as normal.
However Login page should actually be skipped as OnNavigatedTo has same NavigateAsync command.

Side affect which makes no sense is HomeViewModel code gets run when the OnNavigatedTo function runs.

```
 public class LoginViewModel : AppMapViewModelBase
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

    public DelegateCommand LoginCommand { get; private set; }

    public LoginViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
        LoginCommand = new DelegateCommand(LoginUserAsync);
        _navigationService = navigationService;
       

       
    }


    private async void LoginUserAsync()
    {
       
        //This works as expected
        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/MasterDetail/NavigationPage/Home");
    }


    public override async void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);
        //This Executes the code on Home but does not Jump there.
        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/MasterDetail/NavigationPage/Home");
    }


   
}
```

The HomeViewModel code which gets run somehow without ever going to  the Home page.

```
 public HomeViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base (navigationService)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("............HomeViewModel Loaded.................................");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Main OnInitialized in App from

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/Login");
```

to

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/Login");
```

stops NavigateAsync("/..... from being passed through App-OnInitialized

No idea why but it works.